# Python compare two csv files and append data to csv file

Tags: python, csv

I am having two csv files in the following format:

The first is outputTweetsDate.csv:

```
Here is some text;13.09.13 16:45
Here is more text;13.09.13 16:45
And yet another text;13.09.13 16:46
```

The second file is apiSheet.csv:

```
13.09.13 16:46;89.56
13.09.13 16:45;90.40
```

I want to compare these two files and if the two datetime values match add the text and data to one new file (finalOutput.csv):

```
|89.56|,|Here is some text|
|89.56|,|Here is more text|
|90.49|,|And yet another text|
```

This is my code I have so far:

```
with open("apiSheet.csv", "U") as in_file1, open("outputTweetsDate.csv", "rb") as in_file2,open("finalOutput.csv", "wb") as out_file:
   reader1 = csv.reader(in_file1,delimiter=';')
   reader2 = csv.reader(in_file2,delimiter='|')
   writer = csv.writer(out_file,delimiter='|')
   for row1 in reader1:
       for row2 in reader2:
           if row1[0] == row2[1]:
               data = [row1[1],row2[0]]
               print data
               writer.writerow(data)
```

I edited my code and it now works so far, but it does not iterate trough all of my code correctly.
Momentarily my output is this:

```
|89.56|,|Here is some text|
|89.56|,|Here is more text|
```

So it does not show me the third one, even if they are the same. It seems like it is not iterating good through the files.

Thank you!

Comment: Are the rows ordered chronologically? Or can a certain date corresponding to the first row in file1 be in the last row of file2 (or not at all?)

Comment: If timestamps are unique, I would make two dicts using the timestamp as key and merge them.

Comment: @Ofir yes the rows are ordered chronologically

Comment: @Paulo the timestamps in "text.csv" are not necessarily unique, so you can have some text that have the same stamp.

Comment: And if they're missing? i.e there's only one row in either file and not both - discard that line?

Comment: @Ofir I edited my code, maybe it helps you. I only am with the iterating problem now. If there is only one line and no match than it should skip it, I have done this through the "if"-statement

Answer (score 0):

Your second loop reach the end of file2 (outputTweetsDate.csv) before the second line of file1 is read.

Try this snippet :

```
 with open("apiSheet.csv", "U") as in_file1, open("outputTweetsDate.csv", "rb") as in_file2,open("finalOutput.csv", "wb") as out_file:
   reader1 = csv.reader(in_file1,delimiter=';')
   reader2 = csv.reader(in_file2,delimiter='|')
   writer = csv.writer(out_file,delimiter='|')
   row2 = reader2.next()
   for row1 in reader1:
       while row2 and row1[0] <= row2[1]:
           if row1[0] == row2[1]:
               data = [row1[1],row2[0]]
               print data
               writer.writerow(data)
           row2 = reader2.next()
```

*Edit*
The inverse orders are tricky. Let's stop trying to be clever and do some brute force. It will work flawlessly as the files are far less than your RAM.

```
 with open("apiSheet.csv", "U") as in_file1, open("outputTweetsDate.csv", "rb") as in_file2,open("finalOutput.csv", "wb") as out_file:
   reader1 = csv.reader(in_file1,delimiter=';')
   reader2 = csv.reader(in_file2,delimiter='|')
   writer = csv.writer(out_file,delimiter='|')

   rows2 = [row for row in reader2] # all the content of file2 goes in RAM.
   for row1 in reader1:
       for row2 in rows2:
           if row1[0] == row2[1]:
               data = [row1[1],row2[0]]
               print data
               writer.writerow(data)
```

Comment: Hey, in the last row it should be "row2 = reader2.next()" right? It only works if I change the order of the apiSheet.csv, now it is descending and your code works with ascending values. How can I fix this in the code?

Comment: Sry my snippet wasn't debugged. You're right about the last line. To make it work with descending values, just change the test in the while. It's a string comparison, so with string representing dates, row1 is bigger than row2 if row1's date is after row2's date.

For descending order use the test
    row1[0] <= row2[1]

I will edit my response to reflects these changes.

Comment: Now I got the problem, that the code gives me the the first two rows but then the iteration is at the end. This is because row1 is at 16:44 so descending and row1 is 16:45 (third row in outputTweetsDate) so it will never read the fitting 16:45 again because it already was there. Any idea to fix this?

Comment: A simpler proposition, not debugged either, but the idea is there.